# Excel Solver - price per serving change after unit 5

Tags: excel, linear-programming, solver

i have created following excel file that uses the solver to come up with the cheapest possible diet based on the constraints on calories, fat, protein, and carbs. [File here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4f4e7225e7db66cad81cf701ea0fc42020190929135227/ab6294)

i want to add another constraint where the price for potatoes changes to 0.40 instead of 0.15 after the fifth unit. How is this constraint modeled in a linear way in excel?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be modeled as:

```
 potatoes = cheap_potatoes + expensive_potatoes
 cheap_potatoes <= 5
 potatoes, cheap_potatoes, expensive_potatoes >= 0
```

In the objective function, replace `0.15*potatoes` by `0.15*cheap_potatoes + 0.4*expensive_potatoes`. As `cheap_potatoes` are cheaper, the objective (cost minimization) will automatically try to use these first.

This should not be too difficult to implement in your spreadsheet.

PS. The other way around (first 5 are expensive, after that cheaper) is also common (volume discount). This is a bit more difficult to model (requires binary variables).